# Spring Cloud Stream - How to read in SpecificRecord if condition met and in GenericRecord otherwise

Tags: java, avro, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I have service A doing operation A when message type A with its unique Avro schema is read from a Kafka input topic and service B doing operation B when message type B is read from the same topic.

I don't want service A to be aware of B's schema or vice versa. If I had two separate topics I would easily set `spring.kafka.properties.specific.avro.reader` to `true` and consume in specific records, but since I don't want schema B to be there inside service A and vice versa (decoupling reasons), what I'm ideally looking for is something like the following.

Inside service A:

```
@StreamListener(value = Processor.Input, condition = "new String(headers['message_type'])=='A'")
public void consumeInSpecificRecord(TypeACompiledAvroClass a){
// Some logic
}

@StreamListener(value = Processor.Input, condition = "new String(headers['message_type'])=='B'")
public void consumeInGenericRecord(GenericRecord b){
// Log and ignore (leave it for service B to process)
}
```

Is this achievable given that setting the `specific.avro.reader` flag to true results in deserialization errors for message B and setting it to false will force me to use generic records even for the first stream listener which I'm trying to avoid.

If not possible, what other alternative solution could be suggested here?

```
Spring cloud stream version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
Spring Kafka: 2.2.5.RELEASE
Confluent version for the serializer: 5.2.1
```

Comment: I think you would need a custom deserializer (it can delegate to 2 different instances of the actual deserializer).

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. Gave this a try and it can work. The only problem is `useSpecificAvroReader` is set only once Confluent's `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer` is initialized and not per message, and the method using the flag is a private one, so can't really override it. It seems to me that the only way around is copying the deserializer's code into a new class and changing its logic there which is not that ideal from the development/maintenance perspective.

Comment: As I said, your custom deserializer can delegate to two different avro deserializers; one with the flag true, the other with it false, and your wrapper decides which one to call, perhaps based on the header you mentioned in your conditions.

Comment: Yeah I guess I was thinking about this the wrong way. I can have two `KafkaAvroDeserializer` instances each with its own config (one generic one specific).
and the custom one routing to them. I was trying to get away with just having one `KafkaAvroDeserializer` which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @GaryRussell I just posted an answer to my question based on your comment. Please let me know if you think more details should be added. Thanks!

Comment: Looks ok to me; you should "accept" your own answer. BTW, you can use `headers.lastHeader()` instead of iterating over the headers yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Gary's comment, I could come up with a custom deserializer that can switch between generic and specific records based on what's in the header. Here's the code for it for class `A`.

```
public class GenericSpecificFlexibleDeserializer implements ExtendedDeserializer<Object> {
  private static final String SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER = "specific.avro.reader";
  private Map<String, ?> config;
  private KafkaAvroDeserializer specificKafkaAvroDeserializer;
  private KafkaAvroDeserializer genericKafkaAvroDeserializer;

  @Override
  public Object deserialize(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] data) {
    List<String> entityTypeHeader = new LinkedList<>();
    if (headers != null) {
      if (new String(headers.lastHeader("message_type").value()).equals("A")){
        return specificKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(topic, data);
      }
    }
      return genericKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(topic, data);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    this.config = configs;
    HashMap<String, Object> specificConfig = new HashMap<>(config);
    specificConfig.put(SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER, true);

    HashMap<String, Object> genericConfig = new HashMap<>(config);
    genericConfig.put(SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER, false);

    specificKafkaAvroDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
    specificKafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(specificConfig, isKey);
    genericKafkaAvroDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
    genericKafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(genericConfig, isKey);
  }

  @Override
  public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
    return deserialize(topic, null, data);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    genericKafkaAvroDeserializer.close();
    specificKafkaAvroDeserializer.close();
  }
}
```

And `spring.kafka.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.deserializer` in your app config has to be set to `GenericSpecificFlexibleDeserializer` of course.